# Run a bash script only when logging on locally but not when connecting to though ssh

Tags: debian, raspbian

I've build an IoT box on top of a Raspberry Pi running Rasbian Stretch Lite.
I want the script to run when logging in locally but not when I use SSH.

When I put the script in
`~/.bashrc` it runs both locally and when I connect over SSH.

In `/etc/rc.local` it fails because it is using frame buffer which is not available before login.

Setup in crontab with `@reboot` also happens before login.

`systemctl` same thing; runs before login.

So I would be ok using `~/.bashrc` if I could test whether I'm connected using SSH or local or is there another way?

It's just a `autostart.sh` script.

I found putting `10.sh` in `/etc/profile.d/10.sh`

```
if [ "`tty`" = "/dev/tty1" ]; then
    bash "/home/pi/config/licence.sh"
fi
```

worked.

Comment: When you log in locally, is there a GUI, or are things in ~/.config/autostart run?

Comment: I was not using GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Like you discovered, there is a difference between running things system-wide (via `/etc/rc.local` or a `cron` job running at `@reboot` or `systemctl`; though `systemctl` does give you a hook for running things after X11 starts up, if that's what you are looking for; but all of these things are owned by `root`, not the user who might eventually log in and use the GUI) and hooking something into your personal login scripts.

For running something when your GUI starts up, the best solution is often to use the desktop environment's session start (autorun or etc) hooks, usually visible via the control panel once you are logged in.

If you are trying to control a shell login hook which runs both when you log in on the console and when you start a terminal in the GUI, there are some differences between platforms, but generally speaking, you probably want to target login shells only, so typically `.bash_profile`. See also the Bash manual page, which has a long section explaining the differences between interactive vs noninteractive shells, and login vs non-login shells.
Again, your platform (Linux distro or etc) might have additional conventions, such as for example shipping a default configuration where `.bashrc` gets invoked for login shells, too.

Upon a successful connection, OpenSSH sets several environment variables. Try something like

```
case $SSH_CONNECTION in
  '')
    stuff to execute
    when you are not connecting
    via ssh ;;
esac
```

in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` if you specifically want to run something only when you do not log in over SSH.

Comment: If you are not using OpenSSH, perhaps edit your question to indicate in some more detail which environment you are attempting to control.

Comment: Since it's bash, you can use -z  to checked whether the variable is empty. Like in `if [ -z "$SSH_CONNECTION" ]; then` - commands inside the "if block" will execute on the console, but not on SSH logins. Find that a bit easier than the case statement. Possibly a matter of taste. Anyway, thank you for the answer!

Comment: You'd want either `[[` or proper quoting of `"$SSH_CONNECTION"` then.

Comment: Thank you, yes. Double quotes added.